# How to put a big selection of files into a namespace in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, namespaces, resharper

I have a few hundred classes, which do not belong to any namespace yet. I would like to select them and put them all into a new namespace. Is there any semi-automated way of doing this in Visual Studio or with the help of a tool like Resharper?

It must work in a way that lets me select the files to put into the namespace, because not all of them should change. Best would be to just select the ones I need in the project and hitting some macro action to add the namespace declaration to the selected files.

Currently I've started opening up the files individually, selecting the class definition and hitting CTRL+K+S to surround with namespace, but this might take a few days.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty easy C# program to write. It's just text file manipulation. Doesn't require updates to the project file or anything. I know I wouldn't spend a few days doing it manually when I could automate it!

Comment: This kind of work is quite typical of perl, or even sed, scripts FWIW. C# will work but those languages were built for text processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply move the files to a folder that represents the namespace you want, then right click on the folder in Solution Explorer and select Refactor → Adjust Namespaces. ReSharper will prompt you for the files to update, and will then update the namespaces in those files. See the docs on [Adjust Namesapces](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. I was about to write a script as suggested by the other comments, but since I already have ReSharper... works great.

Comment: I would like to add, that ReSharper currently only supports "fixing" namespaces by checking where the files are stored and then adjusting the namespace to the folder structure. This is not always as helpful. For example when working in Unity3D, you almost never have folder structure and namespaces in sync. Still, it was very easy to use ReSharper to actually generate namespace declarations and then adjust the output with some regex search and replace.

Comment: Indeed. ReSharper will base namespace name on folder structure. You can remove a folder from that generated name though, by setting the "Namespace provider" property to false in the Properties window when the folder is selected. See [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/CheckNamespace.html) for more details.

Comment: Any possibility other then installing full resharper on my system?